# Binary search on a sorted dictionary text file?

Tags: objective-c, search, sorting

I was wondering if anyone knows of a project/library that can quickly search a dictionary file without loading the entire thing in memory.

I am about to implement my own, but this information could save me quite a bit of time. I will use a binary search on a pre-sorted flat text file. It will be very similar to this:

http://search.cpan.org/~jfreeman/File-SortedSeek/lib/File/SortedSeek.pm

This will be for a 'fast-typing' game on the iPhone, where I check a user entered word against a dictionary for validity. So speed and memory are major concerns of mine.

Any recommendations / advice / thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

why not import your text file into a sqlite .db file and use sql to validate the words?

Comment: I considered doing that. I could create an index on the word column to force a binary search. Do many SQLLite libraries operate the same way (i.e. not storing the dictionary in memory)?